# Special characters to be loaded into xml target of Informatica

Tags: xml, informatica

[The linked image has 2 parts : The one with white background is Expected result to be and the one with black background is actual xml target file from informatica :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvLoj.png) My requirement is: I have one XML target in Informatica. I need the character '&' to go as it is from source into target XML file.

My Scenario is: I have to save "`&#13;&#10;`" as it is in target XML so that it can be used as line feed and carriage return, while in target it is coming as "`&amp;#13;&amp#10;`".

I can use line feed and carriage return in Informatica using `CHR()` function and ASCII numbers, but this will not make my requirement.

So, how can I achieve this....please help?

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem you are facing. Can you show source/target xmls and what is expected output.

Comment: in xml file, if i have Tata&#13;&#10;Ratan. After executing that xml file, we should get as